# Tabs Jquery 1.9

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, tabs

I updated jquery 1.7 to 1.9
In my old code, I had a function that build my Tabs.
After the first tab was selected and showed me the data, I used this:

```
$("mytabs").tabs("select",0);
```

Now, I've changed for this code:

```
$("#mytabs").tabs("option", "activate", 0);
```

but don't tab opens I have to click in it and show me the data in the tab.
How I can resolve this problem? I need in jquery 1.9 active tab 0 and show me the data.

I also tried:

```
$( "#mytabs" ).tabs( "option", "active", 0 );
```

the same problem
So show me the Tab
[image]

then I have to click en first tab and show me the data:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

The correct option is [active](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#option-active), not activate.

E.g.:

```
$( "#mytabs" ).tabs( "option", "active", 0 );
```

Comment: I changed for your suggestion and I have the same problem. don't show me the data. I have to click in the tab and show me the data.

Comment: My tab is built from a query in the database my code is in asp.net mvc

Comment: You should still be able to place the generated code into a jsFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery UI 1.9 uses jQuery 1.6. You might be having trouble because you are using the wrong version.